# Issue with 'context.setResponseContentLength(fileSize)' metthod in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml, jboss5.x

I am using 'jsf-api-2.1.2.jar' file to build a web app with JSF and there I have created an object of ExternalContext. I am usimhg that object to access 'responseReset()', 'setResponseContentType(String)'and setResponseContentLength(int) but it is showing that these method do not exist. I have checked 'ExternalContext.class' file and saw that those methods exist in that class but I am not sure why it is showing them as undefine methods.
I am running this project on Jboss 5.1 server.
Can someone please assist me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post what you have attempted.

Comment: *it is showing* - eclipse -  or do you get an exception during runtime?

Comment: You should not be "using" a jar you hand-dropped yourself. Did you download JSF jars and manually install them in your application server/classpath?

Comment: Hello, Thanks! for everyones response. This issue is resolved form me now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```java
ExternalContext econtext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        econtext.responseReset();
        econtext.setResponseContentType(contentType);
        econtext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        econtext.setResponseContentLength(contentLength);
```

And evrything work fine.

Comment: Correct  but this has afaics no relation to the original problem by OP